# How to run all test-cases from several modules?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have several modules full of test-cases and would like to create one module that runs them all. I tried loading the tests in each of the modules using `TestLoader.loadTestFromModule`, but it always returns empty test-suites. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem there was that I handed in the modules-names as strings, when I should have been handing in module-objects like this:

```
import unittest
import SomeTestModule

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
loader.loadTestsFromModule(SomeTestModule)
```

Really a beginners mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/).  It can also be called programmatically, and it may thus be used to call your tests once you've configured it.